# Javascript encoding long string as csv fail

Tags: javascript, csv, urlencode

I have a method in javascript that returns a long string delimited by comma, then i need to create a csv file with that string, the problem is that when i have a long string it does nothing

this is how I create the file

```
let csvContent2 = csv2;
var encoding = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF";

link2 = document.createElement("a");
link2.setAttribute("download", filename + "DOC.csv");
link2.setAttribute("href", encoding + encodeURIComponent(csvContent2));
```

when i try to trigger `link2.click()` and check the csv file it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `URL.createObjectURL`,

```js
function downloadAsCSV(longCSVString, fileName) {

  const csvBlob = new Blob([longCSVString], {
    type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'
  });

  //for IE11 & Edge
  if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveBlob(csvBlob, fileName);
  } else {
    //for modern browsers
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvBlob);
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });
  }
}

// example
downloadAsCSV('YOUR_LONG_CSV_STRING', 'FILE_NAME_HERE');
```